# Copy file from raw dir to SDcard

Tags: android, file

I want to copy a mp3 file from my app ***raw*** folder to ***/mnt/SDcard*** but i have no idea for this job.

is this impossible?

If you have any answer tell me about permissions that those codes needs;

thanx.

Comment: you will need to add SDCARD permission in AndroidManifest

Comment: yes, i know. but the way of this job(copy file) is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can use to do that :

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myresource);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(somePathOnSdCard);
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

try {
   while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
      out.write(buff, 0, read);
   }
} finally {
     in.close();

     out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this method

```
/**
* @param sourceLocation like this /mnt/sdcard/XXXX/XXXXX/15838e85-066d-4738-a243-76c461cd8b01.jpg
* @param destLocation /mnt/sdcard/XXXX/XXXXX/15838e85-066d-4738-a243-76c461cd8b01.jpg
* @return true if successful copy file and false othrerwise
*  
* set this permissions in your application WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
*  
*/
public static boolean copyFile(String sourceLocation, String destLocation) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if(sd.canWrite()){
            File source=new File(sourceLocation);
            File dest=new File(destLocation);
            if(!dest.exists()){
                dest.createNewFile();
            }
            if(source.exists()){
                InputStream  src=new FileInputStream(source);
                OutputStream dst=new FileOutputStream(dest);
                 // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = src.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    dst.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

for more info visit [AndroidGuide](http://sanathnandasiri.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-make-copy-of-file-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question and replace `assets` with `raw`.

[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)